# How to register multiple types that implement the same interface

Tags: unity-container, enterprise-library

I have a single interface and this is being used by 2 classes. I am using unity configuration to identify the instance based on the interface.

Now I want to know how should i register these types so that i can call the appropriate implementation based on the single interface itself.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. But you will only have access to the member defined in the interface. Post some code about this please.

Answer (score 6):

This is how I do it:

```
        var container = new UnityContainer().RegisterType<IAmImplementedMoreThanOnce, Implementation1>("Implementation1")
                                            .RegisterType<IAmImplementedMoreThanOnce, Implementation2>("Implementation2")
                                            .RegisterType<IHaveDependencies1, WithDependenciesImplementation1>(new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IAmImplementedMoreThanOnce>("Implementation1")))
                                            .RegisterType<IHaveDependencies2, WithDependenciesImplementation2>(new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IAmImplementedMoreThanOnce>("Implementation2")));
```

Comment: I use public static readonly properties on types to access its name.

Answer (score -4):

you should register whichever instance of type you want. If you register both types for same interface you get the only one. One interface for each type, or you provide input parameter for the type you register. 
It acts like container, you put your stuff in and get it back anytime you want with the correct key.

Either you would create another two interface for your two types which are derived from parent interface and register these two interface for your two types, or use input parameters.

e.g.

you have

ClassA : IClass and 
ClassB : IClass right?

So, it'll be like;
ClassA : IClassA , ClassB : IClassB and IClassA : IClass , IClassB: IClass and register IClassA for ClassA and IClassB for ClassB.

input parameters

RegisterType IClass, ClassA>("TypeA");
RegisterType IClass, ClassB>("TypeB");

Resolve IClass>("TypeA");
Resolve IClass>("TypeB");

make sense?

Comment: There is an example I have seen in enterprise library HOL where we can differentiate these references by using the name attribute when you register a type. I will check it out and comeback to you..

Comment: modified my post for input parameter if that's what you were talking about.

Comment: I think this is a really confusing answer to the question.