# Microsoft Unity, Resolving two similar dependencies?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container, containers

I have a scenario using Unity which is a bit confusing... Say I have an AuthenticationService that authenticates users and when successful logs to a text file or database using TextLogger class or DbLogger class respectively. Normally for which ever class I will use in my project I would register appropriately in my module class as below:

```
public class LoggingModule
{
    IUnityContainer _iocContainer;

    public LoggingModule(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _iocContainer = container;
    }

    public void Init()
    {
        //Add any logic here to look in a config file, check a property
        //or any other condition to decide which implementation is registered.

        //register the database logger to the ILogger interface
        _iocContainer.RegisterType(typeof(ILogger), typeof(DBLogger));

    }
}
```

And this will be injected into the constructor of my Authentication Service. However if I wanted to use both loggers at different points in my application, first do I Register both types in my Init method, i.e. the TextLogger and DBLogger?
Second, how does my container know which type to Resolve?

Please help....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109404/how-to-register-multiple-types-that-implement-the-same-interface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Register your both types into container with a name, i.e.;

```
container.RegisterType<ILogger, DBLogger>("DBLogger");
container.RegisterType<ILogger, TextLogger>("TextLogger");
```

and resolve your types using the name parameter, i.e.;

```
var logger = container.Resolve<ILogger>("DBLogger");
```

Comment: Would it be better to create a Constants Class with names for types? I really do not like using string across my app. Otherwise, thanks a lot.

Comment: if you need a few named registrations you may create a constants class; otherwise you may create different containers.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using nested containers and calling `Resolve` yourself, Unity will provide application-wide resolution rather than scenario-driven resolution.

You can achieve what you want using nested Unity containers, but you are probably better off doing the resolution in your own code, particularly as the nested container approach is more for coping with 'exceptions to the rule' in terms of application-wide resolution.

You will need a block of code to determine which concrete type is appropriate for each instance. This code can then be pushed up into a higher-level controlling/orchestrating class that injects the appropriate concrete type into the dependent instances.